# pipenv No such option: --requirements in latest version

Tags: python, python-3.x, serverless, pipenv

command: `pipenv lock --requirements --keep-outdated`

output:

```
Usage: pipenv lock [OPTIONS]
Try 'pipenv lock -h' for help.

Error: No such option: --requirements Did you mean --quiet?
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

the `-r` option on `pipenv lock` command is deprecated for some time. use the `requirements` option to generate the `requirements.txt`

ie:

`pipenv requirements > requirements.txt` (Default dependencies)

and to freeze dev dependencies as well use the `--dev` option

`pipenv requirements --dev > dev-requirements.txt`

> Sometimes, you would want to generate a requirements file based on your current environment, for example to include tooling that only supports requirements.txt. You can convert a Pipfile and Pipfile.lock into a requirements.txt file very easily.

see also: https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/advanced/#generating-a-requirements-txt

Comment: But it shows inter dependent packages too. what normal pip freeze doesn't

Comment: Even better to have reproduceability

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pipenv==11.9.0` to fix this issue without needing to change any script (anyway upgrading to the latest version is recommended).