# Error with pipenv in Dockerfile: No such option: --requirements Did you mean --quiet?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, pipenv, requirements.txt, pipenv-install

I am trying to build a docker image to run an application, the Dockerfile is as follows:

```
#Pull a image
ARG BASE_IMAGE=python:3.9.0-slim-buster

FROM ${BASE_IMAGE} AS requirements-image

# set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment varibles
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get upgrade -y \
    && apt-get -y install netcat gcc cron \
    && apt-get clean

# install python dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install pipenv pytest
COPY Pipfile* ./
RUN pipenv lock -r --dev > requirements.txt

# add app
FROM ${BASE_IMAGE} AS compile-image
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY --from=requirements-image /usr/src/app/requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt

# set environment varibles
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
   ...continue

RUN python3 -m venv /home/venv
ENV PATH="/home/venv/bin:$PATH"
RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 1 \
    && update-alternatives --install /usr/local/bin/pip pip /usr/local/bin/pip3 1

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt


FROM ${BASE_IMAGE} AS runtime-image
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED TRUE
COPY --from=compile-image /home/venv /home/venv
ENV PATH="/home/venv/bin:$PATH"

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 80
COPY . .
```

However, I get the following error:

```
=> ERROR [requirements-image 7/7] RUN pipenv lock --requirements > requirements  3.0s
------
 > [requirements-image 7/7] RUN pipenv lock --requirements > requirements.txt:
#0 1.588 Usage: pipenv lock [OPTIONS]
#0 1.588 Try 'pipenv lock -h' for help.
#0 1.588 
#0 1.588 Error: No such option: --requirements Did you mean --quiet?
------
Dockerfile:23
--------------------
  21 |     RUN pip install pipenv pytest
  22 |     COPY Pipfile* ./
  23 | >>> RUN pipenv lock --requirements > requirements.txt
  24 |     
  25 |     # add app
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pipenv lock --requirements > requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 2
```

I have tried to change the line 23 of the Dockerfile by different commands but it does not work, what is the correct way?
Note: I Cut a part of the Dockerfile to avoid lengthening the code, line 23 that is generating problems is:

```
RUN pipenv lock -r --dev > requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with `-r` is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73681737/6336357). `-r` is deprecated and you should use `requirements` in exchange like follows:

```
pipenv requirements --dev > dev-requirements.txt
```

Comment: I have made the change you indicate and I get the error:
#0 2.108 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/src/app/Pipfile.lock'
What do you think is happening? in line 22 I'm copying the file, right?

Comment: You are not copying it to the right place. At the time you are copying, you are in the root of the file system but when you want to access it you are in `/usr/src/app/`. You either need to set your workdir earlier or adjust the copy location in line 22

Comment: you're right, I overlooked it. thank you very much.